# What is the criteria for Very low quality flag?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, low-quality-posts

I flagged a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690377/jsf-shooping-cart-error) as very low quality, and my flag was rejected:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it.

This post is mostly code, and it looks like the author wrote a bunch of `s`'s on the end to meet a word count (or whatever. I can't remember if there is such a restriction).

If this post is not low quality, why not?

Comment: It's a wall of code to be sure and yes he added the extra *ssss* because of that but it's not VLQ...it's close-worthy as unclear, too broad and probably other reasons too numerous to mention..but not VLQ. Oh, and it's DV-worthy too. The VLQ flag says *"This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed"* In this case, it **could** be salvaged with some judicious editing.

Comment: @Paulie_D What is DV?

Comment: DV = Down Vote..

Comment: @Paulie_D Oh. Duh. Thanks.

Comment: ... and why is this flag available only on some questions and not on others?

Comment: @Paulie_D I disagree it could be salved through editing. The content problems can only be solved by the OP, not by editing by others. Therefor VLQ does apply.

Comment: Editing by the OP is still editing...